# Where does Super POM come from in the config

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, parent-pom

When I look at my effective pom in Eclipse, I can see a load of dependencies and a label stating that this is our corporate super pom which must form part of every project.

I can't actually work out where the super pom comes into play in the config.  I have looked at my settings.xml in maven, and it has lists to remote repositories, and internal repositories - but can't seem to see a link to the super pom anywhere.

It is a muliple module maven project built from an internal archetype, and the parent module has a parent artefact defined...but when I browse the parent artefact, I still cant see how the super pom comes into play.

Any advice appreciated.

Regards

i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The super pom is defined by the `<parent>` tag:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvn</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Got it thanks.  Traced up through the archetype chain in Nexus and found eventually we ended up at our corporate super pom (different from Maven super pom).  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

All pom implicitly inherit from `super` pom which is present in the maven distribution. This pom contains defaults for all maven projects which can be overriden in your maven project. But most of these defaults are not overridden as they typically form the *convention* part of maven as it is a build tool geared more towards convention. For e.g., the default build directory is `target` and hence this configuration is present in super pom as

```
........
<directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
.........
```

For more information and  actual location of this pom  please refer [here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom.html#pom-relationships-sect-super-pom) and [here](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html)

Comment: Thanks, although this looks like a corporate pom, rather than one which is part of the maven distribution, as it states the company name in effective pom, and includes hibernate and a load of spring dependencies.

Comment: great links by the way

Comment: Oh, I missed the corporate word completely in your question. Yes this is general practice to declare a corporate wide (or project wide) super pom which mention general information like corporate/project information and another pom which inherits from this pom which contains all the dependencies to enforce standard dependency versions.